# Review-problem - check for "if you're paying attention"

Tags: discussion, review-queues, disputed-review-audits

Okay, so I failed this one: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15222381 Which seems to have been deleted due to being offensive or similar.

Granted, it might not be a superbly good answer, as it more or less only references external sources, but I fail to see how it is in any way spam, offensive or anything of the sort - it links to images by Edward Munch, non-sexual, and provides no offensive content whatsoever. So I fail to see that the deletion of the answer was warranted, nor do I see why my "Looks OK" answer was deemed wrong (well, I don't really, since the answer was already deleted, but still, I think it was deleted on the wrong grounds). This might be a wave in a tea-cup, I dunno, but I just feel that both the deletion and the "you're wrong"-message was done in error.

Comment: You voted "Looks OK" on a spam post, the poster is a "growth marketer" for the company's product she promoted.  We don't like spam, it is junk food.  Slow down please.

Comment: As far as I could see, the answer was accurate, and the service does what it says in does. While that might not be the perfect answer, again, that's not the reason given, and again, how am I supposed to know that this is a scammer?

Comment: I can haz screenshot?

Comment: *the service does what it says in does* - But that doesn't mean it's not spam. Users can't go around promoting their stuff in all of their answers even if it's a valid solution for the questions they choose to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Comment: Click the links. They're completely SFW

Comment: Okay, I can agree with it being spam, if the user pushes the service repeatedly, that still doesn't mean the reason given for the deletion is correct.

Answer (score 3):

You admit that the answer isn't good by stating:

> ...it more or less only references external sources...

We don't want link-only answers here.  We want answers which will last the test of time and not solely rely on outside resources for context.  Suppose that the site went offline in the future and someone wanted to use this answer; what then?  What would redeem the link-only answer?

This is a valuable lesson to learn.  Slow down and *review* these questions.  Fortunately for you, this is a warning; get too many of these types of failures and you may have to take a break from reviewing for a while.

Comment: Duh. If it had been *marked* as deleted because of "link-only", then perhaps I wouldn't have reacted. Also, while a link only answer is bad, when the answer is about an external service, links are more or less impossible to avoid.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie: Your job as a reviewer is to be vigilant.  You need to understand that not all questions are going to be made crystal clear and served up to you as unambiguously as possible when asking questions of them.